# concerning list and range in random number generator assignment in 100 Days To Code

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, range

```
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Angela (instructor) uses the line

```
 for char in range(1,nr_numbers+1):
```

I used

```
 for char in range(nr_numbers):
```

I seem to get all numbers in random generator.  It will pull a 0 and 9 from time to time.  Why does she use the 1 and +1...does it make a difference?

Comment: I forgot to add the line below in my post                                                        nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

Comment: Both loops will iterate `nr_numbers` times. For instructors code it'll loop `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... to nr_numbers` for your loop it'll start from `0` to `nr_numbers - 1`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.